# javascript if else statement not working. It returns singleStory even if I click on the twoStory image. I have tried != and ---

Tags: javascript

```
const detailedEstimate = () => {
document.querySelector("#btnDisplayImage").onclick = () => {


let houseStoriesLabel = document.createElement("label");
houseStoriesLabel.innerHTML = "<br>" + "number of stories is " + houseStory + "<br>";
document.body.appendChild(houseStoriesLabel);


if (houseStory = singleStory) {
  houseStory.setAttribute("src", "../images/singleStoryHouse.jpg");
  document.body.appendChild(houseStory);
  console.log('please make a choice');
}
```

Comment: `if (houseStory = singleStory)` you are doing an assignment here, not testing for equality.

Comment: in my Javascript as a global variable

Comment: I know, but when I do the ==, === or != it doesn't work at all. I am fairly new to javascript

Comment: === is comparing if the 2 objects are the same, == compares if the 2 object values are the same = assigns the value

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? not sure whats going on exactly with what you have posted

Comment: it won't let me post the whole thing, but here is a snippit

Answer (score 2):

You need:

`if (houseStory === singleStory)`

not

`if (houseStory = singleStory)`

The single equals sign *assigns* the value of `singleStory` to `houseStory`. `===` is what does comparison (or the much-frowned-upon `==`).

Comment: that would' work for me. I can put the whole Javascript cod in here

Comment: it won[t let me, says it's to long

Comment: You might have other problems than the `===` perhaps, but you definitely have to fix that before you can move on to solving those other problems.

Comment: it won't let me post it. says it's not formatted, although I format it in visual studio cod

Comment: const detailedEstimate = () => {
  document.querySelector("#btnDisplayImage").onclick = () => {

    let houseStoriesLabel = document.createElement("label");
    houseStoriesLabel.innerHTML = "<br>" + "number of stories is " + houseStory + "<br>";
    document.body.appendChild(houseStoriesLabel);

    if (houseStory = singleStory) {
      houseStory.setAttribute("src", "../images/singleStoryHouse.jpg");
      document.body.appendChild(houseStory);
      console.log('please make a choice');
    }

Comment: that's a little bit of it, if you need more let me know it won't let me send the whole thing